# Teradata Dynamic SQL with Bind Variables?

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Is it possible to use bind variables in a Teradata dynamic SQL statement? I can't find an example anywhere. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
DECLARE SQLString VARCHAR(1000)
SET SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnA = :variable1';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLString; --Can I pass something here for variable1 or do I have to concatenate and not use a bind variable?
```

Thanks

Comment: How about simple `DECLARE variable1 VARCHAR(1000); SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ColumnA = variable1;`

Comment: In this simple example it makes sense to not use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, but I have a complex dynamic SQL statement that I can't just convert to a normal SQL statement.

Comment: Please post example (do you want to execute DDL inside EXECUTE IMMEDIATE)?

Comment: The table name is dynamic which is why it needs to be dynamic SQL: 'SELECT * FROM ' || TableNameVariable || ' WHERE ColumnA = :variable1'

Comment: As I thought. It won't be possible to pass TableNameVariable as parameter/variable. You could use concatenation approach, but you have to be sure that input is safe to avoid SQL Injection attacks

Comment: That's not the question though. I know you have to concatenate the table name...I'm asking about in the WHERE clause, can that be a bind variable.

Comment: Based on Terradata doc it looks like the only supported syntax is `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement` There is no other clauses like `USING`.

Comment: So the answer to my question is, it can't be done...is that what you're saying?

Comment: I am saying that `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` does not support it. But there might be other ways(packages/procedure/...) so I won't tell that it is impossible.

Comment: Please check prepared statement https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_109A/ch10.12.31.html and https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1148_109A/ch10.12.17.html#ww877675

Comment: That might work, but I don't see an actual example. Do you have one?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Return a result set based on the SQLString? Or Insert/Update/Delete?

Comment: Just do an update...no need to return anything.

Comment: And what data is passed by the bind variable? Data (i.e. a value) or Metadata (i.e. a tablename, columnname)?

Comment: Just a local variable declare in the proc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DML statements with bind variables are usually executed multiple times, thus there are no bind variables when you use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, you must use `EXECUTE/PREPARE`:

```
DECLARE SQLstring VARCHAR(1000);
SET SQLstring = 'update MyTable SET ColumnA = ? where columnB = ?'; -- ? identify bind variables
PREPARE S1 FROM SQLstring;
EXECUTE S1 USING variable1, variable2;
```

See the [Stored Procedure manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/CeAGk~BNtx~axcR0ed~5kw/yfXyvOHMeb77MT9p74QyQA)

Comment: the link is broken